# a question about past conditional clauses

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence, conditionals

I was wondering all the time, how I can express just 'past' with 'if' in English?

And finally I found one sentence,

- if you watched and listened to the previous podcast, you'll find that our favorite teams were Arsenal and Manchester United.

I don't think this is a 'if + past tense and would/could/should sentence.
this is talking about just the real past with 'if', not imagination and unreal.
this is not fixed sentences such as 'past tense + would/should/could or had p.p + would/should/could have p.p.

in common sense, if you use 'if + past tense', the following sentence should be with would/could/should and it also means unreal and a rare possibility. However, the above sentence just indicates the incident in the past with 'if'

LSS, Here is my question.
If I want to talk about just the past like the above sentence with 'if', which tense should I use for the following sentence?
the above sentence uses 'will' which I guess makes a difference with 'would' (unreal conditional)
and it also uses 'were'. Can I just use 'are' instead? does this make a difference?

I also, while searching, found out 'Past real conditional' which says 'if past tense + simple past tense', but I don't think this explains my question.

Answer (score 2):

"Past real condition" is a good way to describe this. The past indicative (normal) tense can indeed be used in an *if* clause, as opposed to a past subjunctive (hypothetical) tense; both tenses have the same form except for *was/were*.

As to what tense should be used in the main clause, it could be be any tense depending on context, though *would/could* and other typically subjunctive verbs are probably less likely.

> If you saw the murderer, you know he was tall.
>
> If you saw the murderer, you will be able to identify him.
>
> If you saw the murderer, please tell us who he is.
>
> If you saw the murderer, why didn't you tell us?

The following examples would be subjunctives, so the conditions would be unreal/hypothetical:

> If you saw the murderer, you would know he was tall (but apparently you don't know, so you didn't see him).
>
> If you saw the murderer, you could identify him (but it seems you cannot, so you didn't see him).

Comment: you are the best!!. I have another sentence too which is quite confusing whether this is just the past indicative sentence or the subjunctive sentence. * Even if Tottenham were ahead of Arsenal all through the season, there'll be one day where they would slip up. I'm confused because of the 'there will be'.

Comment: @SeongEunBae: Yeah, *were* can be subjunctive or indicative in this case, because indicative plural of the past simple is also *were* (subjunctive past is always *were*). But this sentence is, in my opinion, not very well written (though I would be surprised to find this in the sports section of a newspaper). The word *would* ensures that it must be read as hypothetical. The verb *will* is ugly here; the author should not have used it. He might have written instead, *"Even if Tottenham were ahead of Arsenal all through the season, one day they would slip up."*

Comment: thank you so much :) it was a comment from his speech though.

Comment: But it depends on what the writer wants to say, exactly. If he really didn't mean to use a hypothetical condition, but rather a future condition, he could have written this: *"Even if Tottenham stays ahead of Arsenal all through the season, there will be one day where they slip up."* If he had wanted to use a different subjunctive construction, one expressing a possibility, he could have written this: *"Even if Tottenham should stay ahead of Arsenal all through the season, there could be one day where they slipped up."* But I'm really not exactly sure whether he means *stay*.

Comment: @SeongEunBae Ah, OK, if it was a speech, I suppose a sloppy construction can be forgiven!

Comment: Very helpful thanks. I had the same question for a long time.